# Find Header Name in a List and search for each header name in Sheet 1, once found, cut the entire column and move to Column A

Tags: excel, vba

It is me again! This time I'm trying to form a code that will help me arrange columns in my Sheet 1. Basically what I want to happen goes something like this

1. Find EACH Header Name from a list in "Column Names" sheet
2. Search the header name through the entire columns of "Sheet1"
3. If header name is found, cut the entire column with that header name and transfer/paste to Column A
4. Loop to the next header name in the list, rinse repeat

For Example:

1. Find "Column 1" (as listed in column names sheet)
   [image: Name]
2. Search for "Column 1" name in "Sheet1"
   [image: Search]
3. If "Column 1" name is found in "Sheet1", then cut and transfer the entire column to Column A
   [image: Transfer]
4. Loop through the next column name listed in the names list. In this case, "Column 2" until all names are used.
   [image: Loop]

I have the code below.. yes it isn't working yet =(... any help is appreciated!

Example 2:
So it isn't working because for some reason whenever I change the names list to let's say "Dates", "Description", etc. as well as the column names to the those, it does not work =(

Also, I can't seem to find a way to select the names list if I place it in another sheet. Although for this one it's not much of an issue I just need it to work first =(

[image: After]
[image: Test]

```
Option Explicit
Sub ArrangeColumns()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim Position As Range
    Dim HeaderName As Range, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each HeaderName In Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        i = HeaderName.Row
            LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find the last column of row 1

            Set Position = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastColumn)).Find(i) 'Search from column 1 to last column of row 1 for the header

            If Position Is Nothing Then '<- If header does not exist throw a message box
                 MsgBox "Header was not found."
            Else 'If header does exist
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Position.Column).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row of the column that header found

                .Range(.Cells(1, Position.Column), .Cells(LastRow, Position.Column)).Cut 'Cut the column that found from row  to last row
                .Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight '<- Move it to column A

            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is *not working yet*? Can you update your question to include an example of the desired output vs. the current?

Comment: I was going to answer but I got a sudden urge to go make a cheese burger.

Comment: Hello! I tried to update it! Hahahahaha I hope I explained it properly but yes honestly I'm quite lost why it doesn't work the way I want it to be hahahahaha I guess I'm such a bad programmer XD

Comment: Hi, Michael! Maybe a cheeseburger meal along with large fries could help? Hahahahahaha!

Comment: Help pleaseee :)